# What ever happened to Falcon?

Tags: comics, marvel, x-men, avengers

In Avengers X-sanction Cable goes back on his last day to try and kill the Avengers.  In the first issue did he actually kill Falcon?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The character Cable attacks is the Falcon. The goal was to draw out Captain America. He is presumed to have survived the X-sanction storyline.

Answer (score 0):

The Falcon is still alive, he's teaming up with Captain America on [Captain America #10](http://marvel.com/news/story/18396/sneak_peek_captain_america_10).